# Json.Net SelectToken Query not working

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I have a JSON object like this

```
"office": {
    "parkingRatio": 12.0,
    "hasGenerators": true,
    "generators": [
      {
        "_id": "ff2dc672-6e15-4aa2-afb0-18f4f69596ad",
        "office_id": "b62ce2c1-5fa2-4eee-9ce8-e04a2c3e6513",
        "make": "Broom Broom",
        "covered": true,
        "output": 1234.0
      }
    ]
}
```

I have a query like this:

```
$.office.generators[?(@._id =='ff2dc672-6e15-4aa2-afb0-18f4f69596ad')]
$.office.generators[?(@.office_id == 'b62ce2c1-5fa2-4eee-9ce8-e04a2c3e6513')]
```

If I run this on a few online tools like [HERE](http://www.jsonquerytool.com/):

it works fine and gives me the whole array item, but if I run it in json.net v7 it returns nothing.

So i tried  the following thinking it might be string

```
$.office.generators[?(@.covered == true)]
```

And it works in online tool and json.net. So i tried the following thinking it might be the hyphens

```
$.office.generators[?(@.make == 'Broom Broom')]
```

And again it works fine in both. What is wrong with my first query?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. The json _id field gets converted into a JValue of type Guid but the expression JValue gets converted into String so when "BooleanQueryExpression"  does this comparison

```
if (v != null && v.Equals(Value))
```

then its not equal.

I submitted a issue on [github](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/643)